# Discord.js: How do I take everything from an array, and then use every part of the array and react to a message individually?

Tags: javascript, arrays, discord.js

Here is my current code. I want to, as the title says, take everything from an array then react to a message.

```
 reactionCount = args.length // how many choices there are
        reactions = [
            '',
            '',
            '', 
            '',
            ''
        ] // chosen reactions in an array
        
        let toReact = reactions.split(0, reactionCount) //here i try to get the first [n] reactions. This comes out as an array. This is the array I want to take everything from and then react
        console.log(toReact) //test
        message.react(toReact) //test
```

Right now this is trying to react to the message with an array. I am aware I can do this individually, kind of like this (old code)

```
if (args[4]) {
        const sentMessage = await message.channel.send(`**${message.member.displayName} Started a poll!**\n**A)** ${args[0]}\n**B)** ${args[1]}\n**C)** ${args[2]}\n**D)** ${args[3]}\n**E)** ${args[4]}`)
            sentMessage.react('')
            sentMessage.react('')
            sentMessage.react('')
            sentMessage.react('')
            sentMessage.react('')
        } else if (args[3]) {
            const sentMessage = await message.channel.send(`**${message.member.displayName} Started a poll!**\n**A)** ${args[0]}\n**B)** ${args[1]}\n**C)** ${args[2]}\n**D)** ${args[3]}`)
            sentMessage.react('')
            sentMessage.react('')
            sentMessage.react('')
            sentMessage.react('')
        } else if (args[2]) {
            const sentMessage = await message.channel.send(`**${message.member.displayName} Started a poll!**\n**A)** ${args[0]}\n**B)** ${args[1]}\n**C)** ${args[2]}`)
            sentMessage.react('')
            sentMessage.react('')
            sentMessage.react('')
        } else if (args[1]) {
            const sentMessage = await message.channel.send(`**${message.member.displayName} Started a poll!**\n**A)** ${args[0]}\n**B)** ${args[1]}`)
            sentMessage.react('')
            sentMessage.react('')
        } else if (args[0]) {
            const sentMessage = await message.channel.send(`**${message.member.displayName} Started a poll!**\n**A)** ${args[0]}`)
            sentMessage.react('')
        }
```

But I want to save some space.
I want to preface, I am kind of beginner right now, in terms of javascript. I used to be really good, and I could have done this, but I took a year and a half long break and now I am essentially useless.

Comment: Do you mean a `for` loop?

Comment: @ITgoldman sure. How can that be used in this context?

Comment: `reactions` is already an array, why are you using the string split function on it?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans `reactions` is the acceptable emojis to use. I split it because the user who runs the command, inputs a flexible amount of options. If he makes 2 options, it would split the array and erase c, d, and e and leave a and b. Same with 3.. 4.. etc. That is the array I needed to grab everything from, not `reactions` Also that's a typo. I meant splice lol

Comment: and it is an array, not a string, so `reactions.split` doesn't exist, and would have thrown a JS error if you tried to run it. To get a subarray from an array, you use `slice`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok...

```
for (var i = 0; i < reactions.length; i++) {
    var toReact = reactions[i];
    console.log(toReact) //test
    message.react(toReact) //test
}
```

Comment: Or, so much easier, `reactions.forEach(v => message.react(v))`. No need for all the for loop syntax and value unpacking when `.forEach` is right there.